# code or tutorial for how to make call from iphone application without quitting the application

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to make call from application without quitting the application on iphone.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do so.  Certain actions on the iPhone, up to OS 3.1, are strictly controlled by Apple and there is no SDK for them.  The phone and messaging are two such areas.

Comment: Unless you want to implement VoIP like the Vonage/Google Voice apps.